# What is an efficient way to compare JTrees?

Tags: java, swing, compare, jtree

I back up my data to an external drive quite often and have to sift through files I have and haven't already transferred over. I thought it would be useful to create a tool that will allow me to select two directories, compare them, and then transfer the files over with a few clicks of a button.

I'm sure projects of this sort already exist out there, so for me, it is mainly a learning experience.

So to start it off, I have a method that will get all my folders and files so that I can populate my tree:

```
public static void listAllFiles(String directory, DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Boolean recursive) {
    File [] children = new File(directory).listFiles(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { 
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(children[i].getName());    

        if (children[i].isDirectory() && recursive) { 
            parent.add(node); 
            listAllFiles(children[i].getPath(), node, recursive);    
        } else if (!children[i].isDirectory()){ 
            parent.add(node); 
        }
    }
}
```

Once the method is called, I simply create my JTree and add it to my view:

```
myTree = new JTree(parent);
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(myTree);
```

So once I have my two JTrees, how would I compare the nodes to see what files don't exist on my external? Would it be easier to just compare the array of files?

**Edit**

By efficient, I mean is least likely to bog down the computer in case the file tree consists of thousands of files.

Comment: You should be comparing the data behind the `TreeModel`, which is ultimately driving the `JTree`.

Comment: BTW, if you get tired of the learning experience, the tool you're looking for is called `rsync`.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the advice. Vanza, thanks for posting a tool that does what I'm doing. I may look it up and emulate it to the best of my ability :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is:  Why compare JTree's?  JTree is a GUI element for displaying data - not a data structure for storing/comparing/manipulating data.

So what you should do is come up with a data structure to compare your data in, and then use the JTree to display the results of your compare.  Assuming CPU resources are what you want to conserve, I'd say you want to use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Essentially you'd build your `TreeMap` on the source file system, and then remove items from the `TreeMap` as you find (and match) them on the destination file system.  Once you're done with the compare, you can display files that still need syncing in a `JTree`.

Best of all, since TreeMap guarentees log(n) for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` methods, it'll cost you nLog(n) to insert all the files in the source, and nLog(n) to remove (basically your compare) all the keys in the destination.

**Edit**

Oh, and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is one of the best tools I've ever used for file system comparisons.  Of course, I've never used it for syncing a backup drive...

Comment: Indeed, I should have realized that I wasn't necessarily wanting to compare JTrees, but the data inside them. You mentioned to use TreeMap, but what exactly would I put in the map? Would I make the keys be `parent`, `children`, etc and the values would be arrays of the filepaths?

Comment: @WilliamShatner TreeMap's name is a little missleading - it works very similarly to a HashMap from a user's perspective (it just operates differently in the background).  Without putting too much thought into it, I'd say put the full matching filepath (you'd probably cut of `C:/` and such)  in as the key and the actual File object as the value.  That way it's easy to compare which files exist and which don't.  Also, then you have references to files that still need syncing (so you don't have to find them again).

Comment: Assuming the file structures are exactly the same, I wouldn't need to test if the file exists, correct?

Comment: @WilliamShatner - Yeah, you probably wouldn't need to because you found it in the first place (although you may still want to test the last modified date...).  Because you have access to the files in the TreeMap, it should be really simple to do that anyways.